# How to connect to DB 2 Stored Procedure from .net

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures, db2

How to connect to DB 2 stored procedure from .net console application?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow ... what have you tried so far? ... maybe a little google query will help you ... https://www.google.com/search?q=connection+db2+net

Comment: You don't *connect* to a stored procedure - you **execute** it ....

Answer (score 0):

I have done that using the IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.dll and the following code:

```
var connection = new iDB2Connection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
var commandText = "call PROCEDURE_NAME(?)";
var command = new iDB2Command(commandText, CommandType.Text, connection);
iDB2CommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(command);
command.Parameters[0].Value = "Your Parameter Value";

iDB2DataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read())
{
    /* Do whatever you want */
}

reader.Close();
connection.Close();
```

For me the dll was located in C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Client Access